# How to migrate odoo 8 to odoo 10

Tags: odoo-8, odoo, odoo-10

i want to migrate `odoo 8` to `odoo 10` with all settings and data in community edition, can someone please tell me about what steps I should follow or is there any module or other way which it could done automatically???

Comment: Are u talking about the database migration or module migration ?

Comment: Module migration..

Comment: That is not trivial to answer, because there were big changes from 8 to 10.

Comment: Sir can i migrate 9 to 10 with that way???

Comment: if Yes, then what process i should follow???

Answer (score 2):

For Database Migration please check https://github.com/OCA/OpenUpgrade

For code migration you need to be aware for changelogs of odoo versions & you need to maintain that changes in you customized modules.

Answer (score 0):

this is a tool under test to migrate code written in odoo7 to odoo11 
http://odoocodemigrator.online/

as mentioned on the web site work is in progress , and there is a sample included