# Does exist a method to migrate database between different version in odoo

Tags: odoo

Can someone tell me to how migrate odoo v9 to odoo v10. I want to migrate all data in the database. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Migrating Odoo is a non-trivial operation.

If you are an enterprise customer, check Odoo's upgrade service here: https://upgrade.odoo.com/database/upload.

Check this answer to get the idea: [How to migrate odoo 8 to odoo 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41151342/how-to-migrate-odoo-8-to-odoo-10).

You will have to migrate your custom or third-party modules, if not yet available, and then you have to migrate the database.

Some people use Open Upgrade: https://github.com/OCA/OpenUpgrade